# Record Audio with MediaRecorder and play it simultaniously with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, stream, media-player, byte, mediarecorder

currently im doing some researchs in my company for a voip application.

We want to record the sound of the microphone of the device in amr, encrypt it and send the data to our server, from which the other side streams and decrypt it. For some testcase i currently use the MediaRecorder to record sound in amr. Because i want to continusily stream the current sound, i cant use a file to store the data. So i created a pipe and gave it as a file-descriptor to the MediaRecorder-Reference.

```
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = createMediaRecorder();

    //make a pipe containing a read and write parcelFd
    try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor[] fdPair = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
        //get a handle to your read and write fd objects
        ParcelFileDescriptor readFd = fdPair[0];
        ParcelFileDescriptor writeFd = fdPair[1];
        //set the output to the write side of this pipe
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(writeFd.getFileDescriptor());
        //next create an input stream to read from the read side of the pipe.
        FileInputStream reader = new FileInputStream(readFd.getFileDescriptor());
        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(writeFd.getFileDescriptor());

        //now to fill up a buffer with data, only do a simple read
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFSIZE];

        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        //by starting the mediarecorder, it will write into the writeFD
        mediaRecorder.start();

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Start Recording");
        while(_isRecording){
            int length = 0;
            while((length = reader.read(buffer)) > 0){
                writer.write(buffer, 0, length);
                _audioListener.onAudioRecorded(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        }

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Stop Recording");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        reader.close();

        tearDownMediaRecorder(mediaRecorder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The AudioListener will send the read bytes to my Activity where i hold an instance of MediaPlayer which should read the data and play it. I know it make not much sense to hear that, what i just spoke, but its just for testing how i can read the content of a pipe in a MediaPlayer. So thats what my Activity does.

```
ParcelFileDescriptor[] fdPair = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
            _readFd = fdPair[0];
//              _writer = new FileOutputStream(_writeFd.getFileDescriptor());
            _reader = new FileInputStream(_readFd.getFileDescriptor());

            _mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            _mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Media-Player Completed.");
                }
            });
            _mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Error-What: " + what);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            _mediaPlayer.setDataSource(_readFd.getFileDescriptor());
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Set Source of MediaPlayer");
            _mediaPlayer.prepare();
            _mediaPlayer.start();   
        }
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, mAudioTxBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

//          _writer.write(mAudioTxBuffer);
            _reader.read(mAudioTxBuffer);

At the moment i get the following exception from the MediaPlayer if i want to play the received bytes:

```
09-18 10:38:10.785: W/System.err(12136): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
```

I currently dont know if i understand something wrong or i have a bug in the code.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you manage to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

> The application needs to have the permission to write to external
>   storage if the output file is written to the external storage, and
>   also the permission to record audio. These permissions must be set in
>   the application's AndroidManifest.xml file, with something like:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```